# find out the number of multiples of K among the given N numbers

Tags: python

> You are given N numbers. Now you have Q queries. For each query you
> will be given an integer K
>
> **Input Format** The first line consists of number N. Next N line contains N numbers. Next line contains number of queries Q. Next Q
> lines contains Integer K for each query
>
> **Output Format** Output Q lines the answer for every query.
>
> **Constraints** 1 <= N <= 10^5; 1 <= numbers <= 10^5; 1 <= Q <= 10^5; 1 <= K <= 10^5
>
> **Sample Input**
>
> ```
> 4
> 5
> 8
> 10
> 8
> 1
> 2
> ```
>
> **Sample Output**
>
> ```
> 3
> ```

My code, getting one failed test case which uses 78000 inputs:

```
ans = [] 
def countSieve(arr, n): 
    MAX=max(arr) 
    global ans 
    ans = [0]*(MAX + 1) 
    cnt = [0]*(MAX + 1) 
    for i in range(n): 
        cnt[arr[i]] += 1
    for i in range(1, MAX+1): 
        for j in range(i, MAX+1, i): 
            ans[i] += cnt[j] 

def countMultiples(k): 
    return(ans[k]) 

n=int(input())
a=[]
count=0
for i in range(n):
    j=int(input())
    a.append(j)
countSieve(a,n)
q=int(input())
k=[]
for i in range(q):
    c=int(input())
    k.append(c)
i=0
for i in k:
    print(countMultiples(i))
```

Comment: So whats the question?

Comment: This is a CodinGame challenge, right ;) ?

Comment: i have created this code in python but i am getting one failed test case which uses 78000 inputs please help

Comment: What is the error in the failed test case? Time limit exceeded? Or space limit exceeded?

Comment: i am getting run error in one of the test case

Comment: https://hack.codingblocks.com/app/dcb/938

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you create an array of size `MAX(a)` with `a` the list of your `n` numbers. This is inefficient if `MAX(a) = 10^5` for example.

You should find another way to check if a number A is multiple of number B, for example `A%B == 0` (use of modulo).

Try to remove `countSieve` and changed `countMultiples`.

```
def countMultiples(query, numbers):
    count = 0
    for i in numbers:
        if i%query == 0:
            count += 1
    return count

n=int(input())
numbers = []
for i in range(n):
    j=int(input())
    numbers.append(j)
q=int(input())
queries = []
for i in range(q):
    c=int(input())
    queries.append(c)
for i in queries:
    print(countMultiples(i, numbers))
```

**EDIT** :

Here is an optimization. First I search for numbers divisors, for each divisor I increment a counter in a dict `d`, then for a query `q` I print `d[q]`, which is the exact amount of multiples present in the n numbers.

The method to search divisors of a number `n` : I make a loop until the square root of `n`, then for each divisor `i`, I also add `r = n//i`.

I also use a dict `divs` to store divisors for each number n, in order not to re-calculate them if I already found them.

Try this (it succeeded the problem https://hack.codingblocks.com/app/dcb/938) :

```
import math
d = {}
divs = {}

for _ in range(int(input())):
    num = int(input())
    if num in divs:
        for e in divs[num]:
            d[e] = d.get(e, 0) + 1
    else:
        div_list = []
        for i in range(1, math.floor(math.sqrt(num)) + 1):
            if not num % i:
                div_list.append(i)
                d[i] = d.get(i, 0) + 1
            r = num // i
            if (not num % r and r != i):
                div_list.append(r)
                d[r] = d.get(r, 0) + 1
        divs[num] = div_list

for i in range(int(input())):
    q = int(input())
    print(d.get(q, 0))
```

[image: Submission successful]

Comment: This solution exceeds the time limit

Comment: if possible can you write in C++ ? or you can visit https://hack.codingblocks.com/app/dcb/938

Comment: i created this problem bcoz it takes most least time as compare to other solutions like which is given  by phoenixo so time limit matters

Comment: @tobias_k please give the full solution then i can say something abt it

Comment: @AMITKumar : see my edit for an optimized solution !

Comment: Weird. I compared all the algos, and in fact OP's original algo was the fastest... so why is it timeouting?

Comment: @tobias_k: Did you try with the worst case ? With 10^5 numbers, and each number is close to 10^5 ?

Comment: @phoenixo I was using `numbers = [random.randint(1, 10**5) for _ in range(n)]` and `queries = random.sample(range(1, max_k+1), q)` with `n = q = max_k = 100000` (see update to my answer)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could try counting how often each number appears and then checking the counts for each multiple of `k` up to the largest of the N numbers.

```
import collections

n = int(input())
nums = [int(input()) for _ in range(n)]
counts = collections.Counter(nums)
m = max(nums)

q = int(input())
for _ in range(q):
    k = int(input())
    x = sum(counts[i] for i in range(k, m+1, k))
    print(x)
```

At first sign, this does not look much different than the other approaches, and I think this even still has O(N*Q) in theory, but for large values of Q this should give quite a boost.

Let's say Q = 100,000. For all K > 10 (i.e. all except 10 values for K) you will only have to check at most 10,000 multiples (since `m <= 100,000`). For all K > 10,000 (i.e. 90% of possible values) you only have to check at most 10 multiples, and for 50% of Ks only K itself!

I other words, unless there's an error in my logic, in the worst case of N = Q = 100,000, you only have about 1,1 million check instead of 10,000,000,000.

```
>>> N = Q = 100000
>>> sum(N//k for k in range(1,Q+1))
1166750
```

(This assumes that all K are different, but if not, you can cache the results in a dict and then will only need a single check for the duplicates, too.)

---

On closer inspection, this approach is in fact pretty similar to what your sieve does, just a bit more compact and computing the values for each `k` as needed instead of all at once.

---

I did some timing analysis using random inputs using `gen_input(n, q, max_k)`. First, all the algorithms seem to produce the same results. For small-ish input sizes, there is no dramatic difference in speed (except for naive modulo), and your original sieve is indeed the fastest. For larger inputs (maximal values), yours is still the fastest (even by a larger margin), and the `divisors` approach is considerably slower.

```
>>> n, q = gen_input(10000, 1000, 1000)
>>> modulo(n, q) == mine(n, q) == sieve(n, q) == modulo(n, q)
True

>>> %timeit modulo(n, q)
1 loop, best of 3: 694 ms per loop
>>> %timeit mine(n, q)
10 loops, best of 3: 160 ms per loop
>>> %timeit sieve(n, q)
10 loops, best of 3: 112 ms per loop
>>> %timeit divisors(n, q)
1 loop, best of 3: 180 ms per loop

>>> n, q = gen_input(100000, 100000, 100000)
>>> %timeit mine(n, q)
1 loop, best of 3: 313 ms per loop
>>> %timeit sieve(n, q)
10 loops, best of 3: 131 ms per loop
>>> %timeit divisors(n, q)
1 loop, best of 3: 1.36 s per loop
```

Not sure why you are getting timeouts for yours and mine algorithm while @phoenixo's `divisors` allegedly works (did not try it, though)...

Comment: this code is giving an error in time limit exceeded test case 0 failed

Comment: Well, I have no idea what "test case 0" is, but on second thought, this might be just what your "sieve" is doing, except you always calculate the value for each possible K, i.e. always the "worst case"; still, I'm surprised that the time limit should not allow for ~1M iterations. :-/